# Acessing Object property in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrayobject

Hii this is my code for acessing object properties

1.array_push expects parameter 1 to be array , null given in line
2.undefined offset

Trying to get property of non-object

```
Need help on this coded


    <?php

    class product
    {
    public $product_id;
    public $product_size;

    public function __construct($product_id,$product_size)
    {
      $this->product_id = $product_id;
      $this->product_size = $product_size;
     }

    public function getProductID()
    {
       return $this->product_id;
    }
    public function getProductSize()
   {
     return $this->product_size;
   }


    }

    $collection = array();
    array_push($collection,new product("levis",36));
    array_push($collection,new product("US polo",42));

    echo $collection[0]->getProductSize();
    >
```

Comment: __Define__ `getProductSize` method. And correct method is `__construct`.

Comment: What does _i get a huge space_ even mean?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I suppose just a white screen.

Comment: Also, use `__construct()`, there is no `__constructor()` in PHP.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/NLMJH

Comment: I have updated the code and ended up with 2 more errors Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hey just correct your constructor method Name to __construct

```
public function __construct($product_id,$product_size)
{
  $this->product_id = $product_id;
  $this->product_size = $product_size;
}
```